# Why does autorouter revert to 98% after reaching 100%?

Tags: eaglecad, software, autorouter

I managed to route an entire complex board with eagle, or so I thought. At first it worked. Then I began adding large fills (ground planes and VCC planes) in order to minimize impedance.

I now added extra circuitry to my board and manually routed those parts in place.

I now run the autorouter one more time and watched the progress. In all optimize stages, it showed 100% which made me think everything went perfectly. Then after it was done, it reverted back to 98% (1 unrouted wire left).

I turned off the copper layer on the board as well as the grid and I couldn't see where this unrouted wire is and I even zoomed in.

Is this a bug that exists in eagle when I define multiple planes close to each other? or is there some other trick I can use so eagle can stay at 100% instead of reverting to 98%?

Comment: It had so much fun in the last 2% it wanted to share that with you

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured crazy eagle. Yes I'm using 4.16 which is old, but I found the trick.

Even though the part pad is on the correct track, there is a bug in Eagle which won't correctly autoroute the part is the track is previously made.

So the **answer** is to move the part so the pads do NOT touch any of the existing tracks then run the autorouter then it will complete that track.